# Is this possible to prove that $L^p[E]$ is complete without using the concept of "rapidly Cauchy" sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Is this possible to prove that $L^p[E]$ is complete without using the concept of "rapidly Cauchy" sequences ?

In Royden's book, this how it is done. I was curious if there is an alternative approach avoiding the notion of "rapidly Cauchy" sequences. Any Hints/ideas/references ? Thanks !

Comment: This is often done using absolutely convergent infinite sums instead.  The two approaches are trivially equivalent, but depending on your perspective either might seem more natural.